# Turn rectangle mark mode off in org mode in emacs

Tags: emacs, org-mode, cua-mode

How do I disable cua's rectangle mark mode when using org mode in emacs? Ctrl + Enter is used by both modes and I'd prefer to just lose cua's functionality when I'm in org mode since I don't usually need to select a rectangle when editing an org document.

I'm pretty sure I once had some code in my .emacs that performed this function but I can no longer find it anywhere online. Sadly I'm not enough of an elisp guru to figure it out myself.

Comment: With C-<return> you can also use M-<return> for org-insert-heading-respect-content. As result C-<return> use for CUA mode. And M-<return> for org mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use CUA except for the rectangles, so I do

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<return>") 'cua-rectangle-mark-mode)
```

Org mode's bindings automatically override global bindings, so `C-<enter>` runs `org-insert-heading-respect-content` with no extra configuration.

---

I assume you're using `cua-selection-mode` or `cua-mode`, though.  Since it's global you can't turn it off in just org buffers.  Probably the best thing is to define your own function and bind it to `cua-mode`'s map.

```
(defun jpk/C-<return> (&optional arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (if (eq major-mode 'org-mode)
      (org-insert-heading-respect-content arg)
    (cua-rectangle-mark-mode arg)))

(define-key cua-global-keymap (kbd "C-<return>") #'jpk/C-<return>)
```

CUA does things kind of weirdly compared to most minor modes, so while the above works for me it might be wonky if your setup is different from mine.

Comment: Thanks, your function does what I needed. I have a vague memory of cua having an ignore list for rectangle mark mode but I think I'm confusing it with drag-stuff since I see "(add-to-list 'drag-stuff-except-modes 'org-mode)" in my .emacs.